# Click event on dynamically added elements from chrome content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am working on building a chrome extension to be used to simplify some of the eCommerce related tasks that we perform. A content script is loaded into every page with jQuery as a dependency mentioned in the manifest.json file. The main objective is to pick out the element being clicked on the loaded page.

While the above logic works in most of the scenarios, there is a couple of websites(one mentioned below that does not seem to register the click event for a few dynamically loaded elements. For example I click on the color swatch and the content script event is triggered, however clicking on the size swatch which has been modified yields nothing).

http://www.solesociety.com/opal-crystal-blue.html

**Sample Content script code**

```
$(window).load(function(){

    console.log('Content Script Loaded!');

    $('body').on('click', function(e){
        console.log($(e.target));
    });

});
```

I have gone through several stackoverflow questions that suggest adding the selector as the second parameter to the on function will take in consideration the dynamically elements, but I cannot opt for that as my code relies on any element of the body to be clicked.

Additionally I also did a check to see if mentioning the element as the second parameter gave any results but the outcome was the same.

```
    $('body').on('click', '.sizes li a', function(e){
        console.log($(e.target));
    });
```